# ACF - how do you reverse the order of repeater rows?

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting, advanced-custom-fields

I’m trying to sort the rows in the `while` so that they are 3,2,1 instead of 1,2,3. Would be dope if it could be sorted by `$week` as it returns a numerical value. I read the ACF page on sorting rows but given I already have some custom code in here to exclude the last row in the `while` I am not sure how to merge it all.

```
function smile_gallery( $atts ) {
    if( have_rows('smile_gallery', 3045) ):
$i = 1;

$html_out = '';

$html_out .= '<div class="smile-container">';

    // vars
    $rows = get_field('smile_gallery', 3045);
    $end_row = end($rows);
    $recent = $end_row['smile_week'];
    $count = count( get_field('smile_gallery', 3045) );

    $html_out .= '<div class="col-md-6">';
        $html_out .= '<div class="smile-recent">';
            $html_out .= $recent;
        $html_out .= '</div>';
    $html_out .= '</div>';

    $html_out .= '<div class="col-md-6">';
        $html_out .= '<div class="smile-thumbs">';

        while( have_rows('smile_gallery', 3045) ): the_row();

        // vars
        $week = get_sub_field('smile_week', 3045);
        $img = get_sub_field('smile_img', 3045);
        $caption = get_sub_field('smile_caption', 3045);

        // Do stuff with each post here
        if( $i < $count) :

            // vars
            $order = array();

            $html_out .= '<div class="smile-thumb-container">';
                $html_out .= '<div class="smile-thumb-img" style="background: url('. $img .') no-repeat center top; background-size: cover;">';
                $html_out .= '</div>'; // smile thumb img
                $html_out .= '<a class="smile-thumb-week" href="' . $img . '" data-lightbox="smile-set" ';
                if ($caption) :
                    $html_out .= 'data-title="' . 'Week ' . $week . ' - ' . $caption . '"';
                endif;
                $html_out .= '><h6>Week ' . $week . '</h6></a>'; // smile thumb week  
            $html_out .= '</div>'; // smile thumb container
        endif;

        $i++;

        endwhile;

        $html_out .= '</div>';
    $html_out .= '</div>';

$html_out .= '</div>'; // smile container

endif;

return $html_out;
}

add_shortcode( 'show_smiles', 'smile_gallery' );
```

Comment: Read the docs https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/how-to-sorting-a-repeater-field/

Comment: @mokiSRB I read the doc, I mentioned it in my OP. I am not sure how to integrate that without breaking the current logic I have going on.